# Forbid http-equiv="refresh" redirect

Tags: firefox, redirection

When javascript is off (NoScript), a site redirects me and i can't get back to the page i came to.

```
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/badbrowser.php"></noscript>
```

How to forbid such redirect but let me follow it manually (like NoRedirect does), or at least make it leave an entry in page history?

NoRedirect doesn't handle this situation.

Information for other browsers is welcome too.

Comment: What browser are you using? What OS? What other add ons do you have?

Comment: Browser=firefox, the rest doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: Kinda does, as some add ons also affect scripts, more so then just NoScript

Comment: This is **standard** behaviour of browsers to follow this kind of redirect and leave no trace in page history. Now, **how to change that**?

Comment: But name **1** browser that is *completely* based on the open standards of the Internet

Comment: Tell me at least 1 popular browser that doensn't behave this way.

Comment: Is it from Google Web Cache?

Comment: The fact that web standards are made to mistreat users doesn't mean that all browsers must unconditionally comply with the ugly parts of the standard. The `noscript` tag is a big part of a problem, we need to deal with it. Unfortunately both answers to this question do not work with the recent version of Firefox. Hopefully someone finds how to do this.

Answer (score 8):

In firefox, go to `about:config` and search for "refresh". Then, just set [accessibility.blockautorefresh](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.blockautorefresh) to `true` and you're done.

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox 58.0.2.

Comment: @SargeBorsch My Firefox 60 does have that option, and it is the third option from top after *accessability.AOM.enabled* and *accessibility.accesskeycausesactivation*. No need to search.

Comment: The option is present, but it does nothing. I have enabled it, checked what seems to be overall accessibility toggle ("Allow accessibility services to access browser" in Firefox settings), and it still does not block meta-equiv redirects. Don't waste your time with this option.

Comment: Worked for me on Firefox Quantum 66.0.3 (64-bit) on Windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

NoScript → Options → Advanced → Untrusted → 'Forbid META redirections inside `<noscript>` elements'

Comment: There is no such option in the new NoScript which is compatible with FF 57+

Answer (score 0):

A really quick solution:

open Scratchpad (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>)
switch [Environment to Browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad#Using_Scratchpad_to_access_Firefox_internals)
type `gBrowser.webNavigation.allowMetaRedirects = false`
Execute/Run

Congratulations, now the current tab (and **only** that tab) will be immune to meta redirects.

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox 58.0.2. It only produces an exception: "Cannot modify properties of a WrappedNative"

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question looking for a solution in uBlock Origin. In the filters list, you can put a global disable for this type of noscript meta refresh infinite loop shenanigans:

```
*##^noscript > meta[http-equiv="refresh"]
```

This disables all meta refresh directives inside `noscript` tags on all sites.

Answer (score -1):

In Internet Explorer, “Tools” –> “Internet Options” brings up the “Internet Options” window.  Go to the “Security” tab and click on “Custom Level”; a “Security Settings” window will appear. 
It has a bunch of options (settings) in groups; the groups are sorted alphabetically,
and the options are sorted within the groups. 
In the “Miscellaneous” group (about halfway down) there is an “Allow META REFRESH” option (which can be set to “Disable” or “Enable”).

Comment: Is it completely disabled or can i enable single redirects manually?

Comment: Well, of course, you can always “View Source”, copy the URL and paste it into the address bar.  I don’t know of anything better than that; in fact, AFAIK, it doesn’t even tell you that there is a META REFRESH on the current page.